# A better way to test the value of an Option?

Tags: scala, code-readability, scala-option

I often find myself with an `Option[T]` for some type `T` and wish to test the value of the option against some value. For example:

```
val opt = Some("oxbow")
if (opt.isDefined && opt.get == "lakes") 
   //do something
```

The following code is equivalent and removes the requirement to test the *existence* of the value of the option

```
if (opt.map(_ == "lakes").getOrElse(false))
 //do something
```

However this seems less readable to me. Other possibilities are:

```
if (opt.filter(_ == "lakes").isDefined)

if (opt.find(_ == "lakes").isDefined) //uses implicit conversion to Iterable
```

But I don't think these clearly express the intent either which would be better as:

```
if (opt.isDefinedAnd(_ == "lakes"))
```

Has anyone got a better way of doing this test?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

How about

```
if (opt == Some("lakes"))
```

This expresses the intent clearly and is straight forward.

Comment: Sometimes the simplest solution is the best :)

Comment: Won't this still compile even if `opt` is not an Option?

Answer (score 29):

For Scala 2.11, you can use `Some(foo).contains(bar)`

Comment: That's the way I go usually. I just can't understand by this answer is not accepted as the right one.

Answer (score 16):

Walter Chang FTW, but here's another awkward alternative:

```
Some(2) exists (_ == 2)
```

Comment: Daniel, that is *awful*! `:-)`

Comment: I actually like this; avoids one creation & an unapply, and yet is succinct

Comment: This is actually the standard way as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: It's a slight pity that Option doesn't implicitly convert to `Seq`, which would allow for `Some(1) contains 1`.

Comment: @retronym Yeah, but, on the other hand, `Some(2).toSeq contains 2` works. Too round-about for my tastes.

Comment: Perhaps contains should be added to Option directly.

Comment: @retronym Not a bad idea, actually. Go to http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala and open an enhancement ticket if you truly care about it.

Comment: Someone else finally opened that ticket: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6064

Answer (score 7):

```
val opt = Some("oxbow")
opt match {
  case Some("lakes") => //Doing something
  case _ => //If it doesn't match
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use for-comprehension as well:

```
for {val v <- opt if v == "lakes"}
  // do smth with v
```

Answer (score -1):

I think pattern matching could also be used. That way you extract the interesting value directly:

```
val opt = Some("oxbow")
opt match {
  case Some(value) => println(value) //Doing something
}
```

Comment: This does not test against the value - only that it is present. The reason I want to avoid a `match` is that this consequently results in the `else` logic residing in multiple places (i.e. the `case None` and if the value is not the desired one)