# Idiom for Scala's Option when doing equality tests

Tags: scala

What's an easier/cleaner way to do this?

```
val o = Some(4)
if(o.isDefined) {o.get == 4} else { false }
```

I've tried

```
o.getOrElse(null) == 4
```

but that feels wrong, since in the isEmpty case, you end up testing null against the other side... which could itself be null. I need it to be if opt is defined && opt.get == whatever. I feel like some method on Option should just take a function, and I could do it like so:

```
o.test( (x) => x == 4 )
```

and it would apply the function only if o.isDefined.

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611872/a-better-way-to-test-the-value-of-an-option -- which, in fact, is the first "related" question listed.

Comment: I didn't come up when I searched. Thanks for linking them.

Answer (score 23):

This is the cleanest, most idiomatic way to do it.

```
val o = Some(4)
o.contains(4) // true
o.contains(5) // false
```

There is also a predicate version of this:

```
val o = Some(4)
o.exists(_ > 0) // true
o.exists(_ > 100) // false
```

Only use the predicate version if `contains` is not strong enough.

Answer (score 10):

You could also use:

```
if (o == Some(4)) //do something
```

Answer (score 7):

This seems reasonably clean to me:

```
o.map(4==).getOrElse(false)
```

If you want, you could even add an implicit conversion to add a convenience method for this:

```
implicit def richOption[A](o: Option[A]) = new {
  def test(p: A => Boolean): Boolean = o.map(p).getOrElse(false)
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the '==' after the 4?

Comment: "`4==`" is a function that tests for equality with 4

Comment: Scala sugar.  4== is treated as an anonymous function of one argument in this case.  More clearly (but more verbosely) might be: `o.map(4.==)` or  `o.map(_ == 4)` or `o.map(x => x == 4)`.  Key point here is that whatever you pass to Option.map() is only evaluated on non-None Options.

Answer (score 5):

How about this:

```
val o = Some(4)
o match {
  case Some(4) => true
  case _ => false
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following seems most intuitive to me, if you don't care about the object creation overhead.

```
val o = Some(4)
Some(4) == o
```

Another unsuggested method

```
val o = Some(4)
val Some(x) = o; x==4 // Edit: will not compile of o = None
```

Comment: The second method fails to account for when o is None.

Answer (score 1):

```
o.map(_ == 4).getOrElse(false)
```